# I use gurobipy to solve a simple problem,but after adding constraints containing exponential terms and solving them, I got a wrong result

Tags: gurobi

I had trouble solving a simple problem with gurobi:

```
e^x+x=lnP
x=1
```

In Gurobipy,it transforms into this form:

```
x+y=temp
y=e^x
lnP=temp
x=1
```

The result is here:

```
Variable            X 

       x            1 
       P      749.103 
       y      2.71828 
    Temp      3.71828
```

---

The code is as follows:

```
from gurobipy import *

model = Model('Antoine')
P = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='P',lb=0)
x = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='x',lb=0)
y = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='y',lb=-GRB.INFINITY)
temp = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='Temp1',lb=-GRB.INFINITY)

model.addConstr(x == 1)
model.addGenConstrExp(x,y)
model.addConstr(x+y == temp)
model.addGenConstrLog(P,temp)
model.setObjective(P, GRB.MINIMIZE)
model.write("test.lp")
model.optimize()
```

I don't know why the result of P is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gurobi represents nonlinear functions by piecewise linear approximations. When I solve the original model on my computer using Gurobi Optimizer 9.5.2, I get the following warning:

```
Warning: max constraint violation (2.9006e+00) exceeds tolerance
Warning: max general constraint violation (2.9006e+00) exceeds tolerance
  Piecewise linearization of function constraints often causes big violation.
  Try to adjust the settings of the related parameters, such as FuncPieces.
```

This means the default automatic linearization is not sufficiently accurate for this model. As suggested in the warning message, adjust the [FuncPieces parameter](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/funcpieces.html) to get a more accurate representation for this model. For example, with `model.Params.FuncPieces=-1` on my computer, I get this more accurate result:

```
    Variable            X 
-------------------------
           P        41.29 
           x            1 
           y      2.71828 
       Temp1      3.71828
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! I am new to using gurobi and I ignored the warning message.The above problem has been solved,Thanks！